# HTTP POST works with bash but not php

Tags: php, bash, curl, saml

Having problem getting a security token from Microsoft Online Security Token Service(STS). It works fine, I receive the token, when using the following bash script:

```
curl -X POST -d @/var/www/extSTS.srf https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf
```

But when I try to fetch the token using the following php-script I get some 'Invalid request' as result.

```
$target_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf';
$data = '@/var/www/extSTS.srf';
$ch = curl_init($target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```

Result of php-script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wst="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust" xmlns:psf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Passport/SoapServices/SOAPFault"><S:Body><S:Fault><S:Code><S:Value>S:Sender</S:Value><S:Subcode><S:Value>wst:InvalidRequest</S:Value></S:Subcode></S:Code><S:Reason><S:Text xml:lang="en-US">Invalid Request</S:Text></S:Reason><S:Detail><psf:error><psf:value>0x80048820</psf:value><psf:internalerror><psf:code>0x80045c01</psf:code><psf:text>Invalid STS request.&#x000D;&#x000A;</psf:text></psf:internalerror></psf:error></S:Detail></S:Fault></S:Body></S:Envelope>
```

My question is what the difference is between the the bash- and php-scripts, why do they not send the same POST?

Comment: Ofc, thank you. Staring at something for too long can really make you blind..
Solved it using:
$data = file_get_contents('/var/www/extSTS.srf');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works using:

```
$data = file_get_contents('/var/www/extSTS.srf');
```

instead of:

```
$data = '@/var/www/extSTS.srf';
```

The latter simply sets a string and not actually load the wanted content.

Answer (score 1):

The '@' prefix to load from a file is magic that is done by the curl command line tool and is not done by libcurl's [CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html) option.

So, you need to read the file yourself and pass in the contents to the option.